# Pyimgur code works on Windows, not on Ubuntu

Tags: python, api, dictionary, flask, imgur

I have a simple code that creates an album in imgur, via pyimgur. This is the code:

```
@app.route('/get_album')
def get_album():
    im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
    new_album = im.create_album()
    return new_album.link
```

(I tried with `im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)` line before the route handlers as well, same thing happens)

On Windows, everything is perfectly fine. However, when I upload the code to my VPS, I get the following error when I try to do something with the api:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __ca                                                                                                                               ll__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi                                                                                                                               _app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in hand                                                                                                                               le_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi                                                                                                                               _app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full                                                                                                                               _dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in hand                                                                                                                               le_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full                                                                                                                               _dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in disp                                                                                                                               atch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/api/imgur.py", line 161, in get_album_link
    new_album = im.create_album()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyimgur-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/pyimgur/_                                                                                                                               _init__.py", line 754, in create_album
    resp = self._send_request(url, params=payload, method='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyimgur-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/pyimgur/_                                                                                                                               _init__.py", line 687, in _send_request
    result = request.send_request(url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyimgur-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/pyimgur/r                                                                                                                               equest.py", line 91, in send_request
    content = resp.json()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I updated flask to the latest version, and I've been using pyimgur 4, latest release I got from github (pip install doesnt work so I had to install it manually, on both Windows and Ubuntu, since some error about setup.py pops out. I used `python setup.py install` command)

Comment: `resp` seems to be a dictionary, so somehow `self._send_request()` did return something else than you expected. Can you dump it, e.g. with print `dir(resp` or with `import pprint; pprint.pprint resp` ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your insight. I tested with printing and the result was an object, <Request 200>, something like that, so not that helpful, but upon more investigation, I solved the issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have found a solution. The solution was a change in requests module, which probably came along with updated flask or something, so the old method didn't behave like it used to. I updated the requests as well on my VPS (forgot to do it when upgrading flask), and the issue is now solved.